# SQL Server 2008 Provide Value Once for Multiple Instances in Select statement

Tags: select, sql-server-2008-r2

Thanks in advance for your help.

I'm working with an existing query that is called CustSalesbyRoute.  I've made a recent change to it to get a distinct count of Route Stops by Customer and this information is stored in a separate table I created for CustRouteStops.  However, the query also includes Product Family so this duplicates my distinct Route-Stop count.  I've confirmed that several reports use Product Family from this table to pull various data, otherwise, I would eliminate this column and everything would work great.  I also know that this essentially goes against relational database integrity; however, I'm left to work on it, and I'm hoping to have a solution that is equivalent to Excel's FREQUENCY/MATCH functions or SUMPRODUCT, etc.

The question is this:  Is there a way to display the Customer Route-Stops value for the first instance of rows that have multiple Product Family values and show 0 for any others for the same Customer/Route combination?  For example, below is what the query is doing now if I include Product Family:

```
CustID    ProdFamily    Route   #ofStops 
10001     Dairy          101      14
10001     Dry Groceries  101      14
10001     Meat           101      14
```

This is what I would like to see happen because I need to leave Product Family in the table:

```
CustID    ProdFamily    Route  #ofStops 
10001     Dairy          101     14  <<< 1st instance will provide the Stops value
10001     Dry Groceries  101      0  <<< remaining rows for same Cust# and Route will show 0
10001     Meat           101      0
```

Thanks again!

Comment: How do you distinguish the "first" row from the others. Your example data does not contain any information to go by. Remember, the result of a query is a result-set and a set does not have an intrinsic order, so you need something to order by or some other way to identify the first record.

Comment: Well, right, and I suppose that's part of the question.  In other words, say we take the example I provided above, which creates duplicate rows with the distinct CustID/Route combo. This shows the customer with 14 stops (let's say within that month) for each ProdFamily providing inaccurate #ofStops.  So, I tried a case when counts the number of duplicate distinct CustID/Route combo and if the count is >1 then only provide the #ofStops once, not on all rows.  If it is <= 1 then the #ofStops is ok.  The case when I have now is not recognizing the dupe rows.

Comment: Also, to clarify, it doeesn't have to be the "first" instance, just as long as the #ofStops only shows up once for that CustID/Route. Otherwise, it will show 0.

Comment: It look as if I as able to figure it out by looking at some posts regarding partition by... Maybe this might help someone else out that needs a similar solution. We can consider this answered for now:  case when Row_Number() over (partition by salestrans.Branch, salestrans.CustId, isnull(salestrans.Route, ' ') order by ProdFamily) = 1 
then max(isnull(Stops,0)) else 0 end else 0 end as Stops